# Android Multiple Screen - Using dp for UIs

Tags: android, fullscreen

Okay!
I am developing android application right now, but I want to know how I can fit all the layoutouts to the a multiple device screens.

*** I did made multiple screen folders.

res/layout-small/main.xml

res/layout-normal/main.xml

res/layout-large/main.xml

res/layout-xlarge/main.xml

*** Here is an example of my code.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@sting/button1" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@sting/button2" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@sting/button3" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="@sting/button3" >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I used 120dp for every buttons.
When I ran in the virtual device machine, the screen is fit. (Because I used 480dp width screen in virtual device machine.)
However, when I ran in real cell phone devices (Mine: SamSung Galaxy Note 1(Korean version), my dad's: SamSung Galaxy S2(Korean version), and my mom's: SamSung Galaxy S(Canadian version)), even though I created different screen size of folders, I can see the (width) of the button is go too far from the device's screen layout.
Can anyone tell me how I can fit to all the device screen?
Can I still use dp in this case? (Please give me an example too!)

Comment: you should be using `wrap_content` or `match_parent`

Comment: @tyczj Thank you for your reply. I did use wrap_content, it looks bad. I don't like normal button style.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on using `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` (and other layouts).  You're not using their layout parameters at all.  You shouldn't need to specify any specific size (like 120dp) to support multiple screen sizes for your situation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Here's what you should do:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@sting/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@sting/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@sting/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@sting/button4"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Then what should I do for height if same happening for height? Height does not apply to "android:layout_weight" so..

Comment: What do you want the height to be?